# Understanding cdist() function

Tags: python, pytorch

What does this [new_cdist()](https://github.com/huawei-noah/AdderNet/issues/6#issuecomment-594212162) function actually do? More specifically:

1. Why is there a `sqrt()` operation when the AdderNet paper does not use it in its backward propagation equation?
2. How is `needs_input_grad[]` used?

```py
def new_cdist(p, eta):
    class cdist(torch.autograd.Function):
        @staticmethod
        def forward(ctx, W, X):
            ctx.save_for_backward(W, X)
            out = -torch.cdist(W, X, p)
            return out

        @staticmethod
        def backward(ctx, grad_output):
            W, X = ctx.saved_tensors
            grad_W = grad_X = None
            if ctx.needs_input_grad[0]:
                _temp1 = torch.unsqueeze(X, 2).expand(X.shape[0], X.shape[1], W.shape[0]).permute(1, 0, 2)
                _temp2 = torch.unsqueeze(W.transpose(0, 1), 1)
                _temp = torch.cdist(_temp1, _temp2, p).squeeze().transpose(0, 1)
                grad_W = torch.matmul(grad_output, _temp)
                # print('before norm: ', torch.norm(grad_W))
                grad_W = eta * np.sqrt(grad_W.numel()) / torch.norm(grad_W) * grad_W
                print('after norm: ', torch.norm(grad_W))
            if ctx.needs_input_grad[1]:
                _temp1 = torch.unsqueeze(W, 2).expand(W.shape[0], W.shape[1], X.shape[0]).permute(1, 0, 2)
                _temp2 = torch.unsqueeze(X.transpose(0, 1), 1)
                _temp = torch.cdist(_temp1, _temp2, p).squeeze().transpose(0, 1)
                _temp = torch.nn.functional.hardtanh(_temp, min_val=-1., max_val=1.)
                grad_X = torch.matmul(grad_output.transpose(0, 1), _temp)
            return grad_W, grad_X
    return cdist().apply
```

I mean that it seems to be related to a [new type of back-propagation equation and adaptive learning rate](https://github.com/huawei-noah/AdderNet/issues/5).

Comment: This is explained in their paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1912.13200.pdf Do you have a more specific question? Other than that, I would consider sending an email to the authors, instead.

Comment: @Berriel Why is there _sqrt()_ operation when the AdderNet paper does not use it in [its backward propagation equation](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1912.13200.pdf#page=4) ?

Comment: How is _needs_input_grad[]_ used ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the AdderNet paper does use the `sqrt`. It is in the adaptive learning rate computation (Algorithm 1, line 6). More specifically, you can see that Eq. 12:

[image]

is what is written in this line:

```
# alpha_l = eta * np.sqrt(grad_W.numel()) / torch.norm(grad_W)
grad_W = eta * np.sqrt(grad_W.numel()) / torch.norm(grad_W) * grad_W
```

and the `sqrt()` comes from Eq. 13:

[image: adaptive learning rate]

> where `k` denotes the number of elements in `F_l` to average the l2-norm, and `η` is a hyper-parameter to control the learning rate of adder filters.

---

About your second question: `needs_input_grad` is just a variable to check if the inputs really require gradients. `[0]` in this case would refer to `W`, and `[1]` to `X`. You can read more about it [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/extending.html).

Comment: What is the actual purpose of _temp1 and _temp2 in the calculation for backward propagation ?

Comment: and is there any chance that this _new_cdist()_ is related directly to [the GPU out-of-memory runtime error](https://github.com/huawei-noah/AdderNet/issues/6#issuecomment-613362421) ?

Comment: @kevin Yes, it definitely could be a reason for OOM, since `cdist` can require a lot of memory. In SO, it is not recommended to have multiple question in one, so I'd suggest you to ask a new question. If this has answered the original question, consider marking it as answer. You can post the link to the new question here, if you want.

Comment: What about _temp1 and _temp2 ?

Comment: @Berriel See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61241523/replacing-torch-cdist-function-to-eliminate-gpu-out-of-memory-runtime-error

Comment: @Berriel I was told that __temp1 = torch.unsqueeze(X, 2).expand(X.shape[0], X.shape[1], W.shape[0]).permute(1, 0, 2)_ seems to use up a lot of GPU memory during [intermediate calculation](https://github.com/promach/PyTorch-YOLOv3/blob/addernet/adder.py#L29) . But how to modify this line to use less GPU memory ?

Comment: I was told to either

    decrease the tensors dimension, then increase the tensors dimension again _OR_
    increase the tensors dimensions and then use depth-wise convolution _OR_
    use mixed-precision training.

I know I can use https://github.com/NVIDIA/apex for the mixed precision training.
However, I am not sure how to modify the code for suggestions 1 and 2 above.

Comment: @Berriel is there a way to replace torch.cdist() which contains [contiguous() calls](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/understanding-cdist-function/76296/12?u=promach) ?

Comment: Why is `_temp = torch.cdist(_temp1, _temp2, p).squeeze().transpose(0, 1)` required here ?